# Custom cell and UITableViewCell problems

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Newbie here, just learning!

I'm trying to create a table view app with just three custom cells. Each cell needs to have an a label and an image on the left (so far I've only bothered with the label part).  So far [this guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGvs1XqTae0)

has been very useful. I created an array with three items and got it to load just fine, but when I tried to implement a custom cell everything broke. For this portion of code:

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CustomCell";

    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)
    [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil){
        NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                    loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell"
                                    owner:nil options:nil];

        for(id currentObject in topLevelObjects)
            {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
                {
                    cell = (CustomCell *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

    cell.issue.text = array objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

I get the errors `Unused variable CellIdentifier`, `CustomCell undeclared`, `Expected expression before ) token` and `Control reaches end of non-void function`.

I don't know what would cause these and I'm kind of at a dead end as far as my knowledge of what to look for. Sorry for my newbness, and any pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.

edit:
Heyooo!  Thanks, importing CustomCell fixed a ton of the problems!  Now there are no visible errors before running it, but when I try and run it, I just get sent to

```
// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [array count];
```

with a red arrow pointing to return [array count];

The current array code I have is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [array addObject:@"Eleven"];
    [array addObject:@"Ten"];
    [array addObject:@"Nine"];
```

Wow, what a helpful and responsive community.  Can't thank you enough.

Comment: If you click on the red arrow does it give you a message regarding the issue? If in Xcode4 you can use Cmd-4 to possibly see the build error.

Answer (score 3):

All you need is import declaration of CustomCell class.

```
#import "CustomCell.h" // for example.
```

Comment: try replace 
'return [array count]' 
with just 
'return 3'
If it helps, than issue with dealing with array itself.

Comment: Smart idea, but still breaks...?  Strange.

Comment: Weird, it breaks in more places too.  [Here](http://i.imgur.com/fwiEn.png) are all the breaks.

Comment: There at least another error - change 'isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]' to 'isKindOfClass:[CustomCell class]'.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just missed a step. Have you made CustomCell.m, CustomCell.m and CustomCell.xib files? If so, you will need to import the header file.

```
#import "CustomCell.h"
```

Comment: Yup, I did that.  Importing the header was the prob so far.  Thanks ^_^